# Cannot read program output from pipe, but it does move to file when redirected caled by subprocees python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, swi-prolog

I am trying to use subprocess to call an swipl.exe (prolog interpreter) and simulate terminal interaction via pipes.

```
USE_UNIVERSAL_ENDLINES = True

proc = subprocess.Popen([SWI_PROLOG_PATH,PROLOG_FILE_PATH],bufsize=0,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=USE_UNIVERSAL_ENDLINES)

def output_reader(proc,sms):
    while True:
        c= proc.stdout.read(1)
        print('got data in pipe')
        sms.add_data(c)


def error_reader(proc,sms):

    while True:
        c = proc.stderr.read(1)
        # sms.add_data(c)


def input_sender(proc):
    while True:
        input_data = input()
        proc.stdin.write((input_data + '\n') if USE_UNIVERSAL_ENDLINES else (input_data + '\n').encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
        proc.stdin.flush()
        print('send: ' + input_data)

to = threading.Thread(target=output_reader, args=(proc,global_sms))
to.start()
te = threading.Thread(target=error_reader, args=(proc,global_sms))
te.start()
ti = threading.Thread(target=input_sender, args=(proc,))
ti.start()
```

this setup works with simple echo program that reads input and print to output.
Notice also that i set bufforsize to 0 which should mean no bufforing.

As a response i get message via piped stderr:

```
recieved : Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.1)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).
```

but not a single character from piped stdout and i should see at least '1 ?-'

when i use terminal to redirect output
`c:\Program Files\swipl\bin>swipl c:/agh/s9/SE/project/pp.pl > c:/agh/s9/SE/project/prolog_out.txt`

and in file i get:
`1 ?-`

Meaning a) swiprolog does send something down it's stdout
b) for reasons unknown to me i do not get anything in pipe, even though i try to read single character.

Question:
how to read what swiprolog writes to stdout? I am aware of existence of pyswip. I do not wish to use it, cause redoing prolog file would take probably more time than fixing this

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone stumbles with similar problem not willing to use any other api, SWI-Prolog seems to go into buffering output mode if both stdin and stdout are redirected. (only when both, which was quite hard to find). Adding a procedure with (or adding as first in procedure you want to call):

```
set_stream(current_output, tty(true))
```

it will force stdout to work in terminal mode and not buffer, allowing for message communication via pipes.